# How to insert data in database in android I am getting some error?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting this error. Please give me some tutorials. So that I can improve.

**Please do not down vote this is been asked by my student**

```
01-17 16:07:05.234: E/AndroidRuntime(26559): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE table(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY Autoincrement,date INTEGER,quantity TEXT,materialTEXT ;)
01-17 16:07:05.234: E/AndroidRuntime(26559):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-17 16:07:05.234: E/AndroidRuntime(26559):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
01-17 16:07:05.234: E/AndroidRuntime(26559):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:686)
```

Comment: please do not downvote . very sorry for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in log create table query require space between `material` column name and `TEXT` data-type:

```
CREATE TABLE table(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY Autoincrement,
                        date INTEGER,quantity TEXT,material TEXT) ;
```

Comment: Prosper K's answer is correct.. I also suggest you not to use "table" as table name as best practice... As far as possible do not use reserve words as entity names...